# Can Katalon Studio read CAPTCHA number while running a test

Tags: testing, automated-tests, captcha, katalon-studio

I want to test login using Katalon, but I use CAPTCHA. The number in CAPTCHA is always changed. Can Katalon read that while running a test?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that.

CAPTCHA means "Completely Automated Public Turing test to tell Computers and Humans Apart". 
So, the whole point of CAPTCHA is it cannot (or shouldn't) be automated.

You can either talk to the developers and try to remove it for testing purposes. Or you can use a service like [Death by CAPTCHA](https://www.deathbycaptcha.com/user/login).

Answer (score 0):

The primary purpose of `CAPTCHA` is that it should not be automated. If that is not the case, then the whole purpose of having a CAPTCHA is defeated at first place. I don't think Katalon or any other automation tool should be able (and would be able) to automate `CAPTCHA`.